# Terms of Service - Internationalization

Tags: feature-request, legal, terms-of-service, internationalization

IMHO Nothing worth reading should be read translated, but Stack Exchange is being internationalized (this is not real news). Because I am unable to read and clearly understand the terms of service, I would like to have available a version in Spanish.

As these are legal documents, they exceed my translation skills and probably should be revised by an American bi-lingual lawyer.

I encourage you to extend this to the other internationalized sites. Ultimately, in those sites, there are many users who are not able to read English.

https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service

Comment: Although not all of the terms read, is an important part of all.

Comment: The problem with translating Terms is that SO will have to say "You have to read the English version and understand it because in the event of a conflict, the English version prevails." This then leads to issues where the translation might be viewed as inducement or at least misleading, and then parts of it become unenforceable... At least, that's my take on the situation.